# How to fill arrays with object parameter based of a value?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, object

If I have a certain number of objects which each take multiple parameters, how can I fill an array with one particular parameter for all objects, but have the order of the elements in the array based off another parameter. For example, I have this code:

```
public CollegeList(double gpa, int act, int sat, String name, String location){
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.act = act;
    this.sat = sat;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    if(act/36.0>sat/2400.0){
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(act/36.0)*100.0;
    }else{
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(sat/2400.0)*100.0;
    }
    this.scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;

}

public double getGpa(){
    return this.gpa;
}   
public int getAct(){
    return this.act;
}
public int getSat(){
    return this.sat;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public String getLocation(){
    return this.location;
}
public double getScore(){
    return this.score;
}
public double getScoreDistance(){
    return this.scoreDistance;
}
```

Here, I would like the name parameter for all objects that I may create to populate a String array, but have those names go in ascending order by the double scoreDistance in the array. I'm sorry if the wording of this question is bad, but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think it's better to use an ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Create a `CollegeList[]` or `ArrayList<CollegeList>` containing the objects you want to sort.

2)  Create a `Comparator<CollegeList>` that compares two `CollegeList` objects by comparing the `scoreDistance`.  In Java 8 (yes, I know this isn't available for Android, but other readers may find this useful):

```
Comparator<CollegeList> compareByScoreDistance = (CollegeList a, CollegeList b) -> Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
```

In Java 7:

```
Comparator<CollegeList> compareByScoreDistance = new Comparator<CollegeList>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(CollegeList a, CollegeList b) {
         return Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
     }
};
```

3) Sort the array or `ArrayList` using the comparator.  If it's an array:

```
Arrays.sort(theArray, compareByScoreDistance);
```

If it's an `ArrayList`, use `Collections.sort` instead of `Arrays.sort`.

4) Now you can create the string array by going through the `CollegeList[]` or `ArrayList<CollegeList>` and creating an array or `ArrayList` using `getName()`.  For example, if your list is an `ArrayList`, then you can use this from @user3717646's answer:

```
for (CollegeList collegeList : theList) {
    nameList.add(collegeList.getName());
}
```

Or using Java 8:

```
String[] names = theList.stream().map(CollegeList::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(theList.stream().map(CollegeList::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**EDIT:** Code has now been tested, and several mistakes fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ArrayLists. Following sample code is given for two CollegeList objects.

```
ArrayList<CollegeList> collegeLists=new ArrayList<>();  // To store all CollegeList Objects
ArrayList<String> nameList=new ArrayList<>();  // To store Names

CollegeList cl1=new CollegeList(12, 45, 5, "Name1", "Location1");
CollegeList cl2=new CollegeList(12, 45, 5, "Name2", "Location2");

collegeLists.add(cl1);
collegeLists.add(cl2);

for (CollegeList collegeList : collegeLists) {
    nameList.add(collegeList.getName());
}
```

collegeLists stores all CollegeList objects.

then you can get each and every parameter using get methods and put the in to seperate aarraylists.

If you want to sort the arraylist, You can uose `Collections.sort(nameList);` to do it.

Comment: Not quite right...the questioner does _not_ want to sort the `nameList` in alphabetical order.  So `Collections.sort(nameList)` can't be right.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to show you haw to sort an ArrayList. Do the same thing if you want to sort a number array also. @ajb